# Cannot connect to internal IP address from external IP address

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, ssl, http, raspberry-pi

I just installed the Apache2 webserver on my Raspberry Pi, and tried to forward port 80 & 443 to it. It has the internal IP `10.0.0.11`.

The Raspberry Pi is behind two routers. (router-IP `192.168.1.13` or `10.0.0.1`)
My problem is that when I try to connect to my server trough my external IP (`87.245.xx.xx`) it just leads me to the IP `10.0.0.11`.

This result is that I can connect to it while I’m in my `10.xx.xx.xx` network, but not if I’m outside of it.

Can anyone help me figure out what I did wrong?

Config of port-forwarding / triggering of my router in the `192.x.x.x` network.

[image]

Config of port-forwarding / triggering of my router in the 10.x.x.x network.

[image]

I tried port-forwarding instead of port-triggering too, but it also won’t work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to use Port Forwarding, not Port Triggering. How exactly do you end up at your internal IP? Is it perhaps a redirect sent by the web server on your Pi?

Comment: Alright, I changed it to port forwarding. (Unfortunately it still doesn't work). Every time I try to connect to my Pi trought the external IP (from an external PC) I end up receiving the IP 10.0.0.x, which results in an error because I'm not in the 10.xx.xx.xx network.

Comment: Connecting by IP doesn’t “receive IPs”. Please use a non-redirecting protocol like SSH to test. Then, if your problem is indeed HTTP-specific, open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

The router with external IP ( 87.245.x.x) must be in 10.0.0.x sub-net.
RaspberryPi must have defualt gw configured with 10.0.0.x gateway

Try to acces it ( http[s]://87.245.x.x) outside of your LAN. With your PC probably not work because port-forwarding/triggering is only listening for WAN packets